# How to set the text automatic color in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, editor

[image]

The ckeditor default text color is #333333, I wonder are there any way can set the color to #000000?

I have tried open the contents.css in the plugin folder

```
body
{
    /* Font */
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Verdana, "Trebuchet MS";
    font-size: 12px;

    /* Text color */
    color: #333;

    /* Remove the background color to make it transparent */
    background-color: #fff;

    margin: 20px;
}
```

and change the color:#333 to #000000 but it does not change anything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hum... Try changing it to #f00 and see if it really changes nothing.

Comment: make sure you clear your browser's cache after changing. ckeditor does some heavy caching!

Comment: change the color to #000 and the background color to #222

Comment: or you could use e.editor.document.getBody().setStyle('color', 'black');

Comment: Thanks ,  the reason is need to be #000 but not #000000...

Comment: @user3538235 i will post this as an answer then. hopefully u will accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the contents.css change the color to `#000` (not #000000) and the background to `#222` (transparent) and then your text will be black on a transparent background. you can use #fff if you want a white background.

Comment: in CSS #000 is just the same that #000000 and I don't know why you think that transparent is #222

Comment: @AlfonsoML in ckeditor it uses the 3 digit format not the 6 digit. I'm guessing you don't use it.

Comment: Does ckeditor consider `222` to be transparent, instead of actual `222` color? Highly doubtful.